# Recursion Backtracking to print all combinations of binary numbers of length N without using loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Need help to print all combinations of binary digits using recursion and no loops.

```
void printBinary(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        cout << "0" << endl;
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        // How do I call?
    }

}
```

Sample output for `printBinary(3)`:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: is "completing" means I can't change the existing code?

Comment: you are free to change the code

Comment: Tagging [tag:c++] is sufficient, adding it in the title is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your recursion is you didn't save your answer

this part will give you difficulties:

```
if(n==1)
    {
         cout << "0" << endl;
         cout << "1" << endl;
    }
```

from those part, I think you want to "every state of recursion, print the correspondent digit, then after n-th recursion print the last digit"

It will be easier if you think "every state of recursion, decide the digit value then pass it to other state, then after n-th recursion print the passed value"

this is how I implement it in C++:

```
void bin(int n, string answer){
    if(n==0){
        cout << answer << endl;
    }else{
        bin(n-1, answer+"0");
        bin(n-1, answer+"1");
    }
}
```

and when you call it `bin(3,"")` it will give you:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: Why is there Python here?

Comment: oh, sorry I code it with python at first, I'll edit and delete it

Answer (score 1):

As the number of digits increase the total number of answers increase by 2 times, therefore you will have to call a function two times

```
vector <string> getall(string k,int req){
    if(k.length()==req) return {k};
    vector <string> C;
    vector <string> D;
    k.push_back('0');
    D = getall(k,req);
    if(D.size()>0) C.insert(C.end(),D.begin(),D.end());
    k.pop_back();
    k.push_back('1');
    D = getall(k,req);
    if(D.size()>0) C.insert(C.end(),D.begin(),D.end());
    k.pop_back();
    return C;
}
```

So just call this function with an empty string and req as the number of digits you want to print, it will print in increasing order as we are selecting 0 first otherwise if we select 1 first decreasing order will be printed.

```
string k = "";
int req = 5;
vector <string> s = getall(k,req);
```

And if you want to just print instead of returning in the first line you can print it over there.

Answer (score 1):

This is c version

```
void bin(int n, char *answer,int size){
if(n==0){
    printf("%s\n", answer);
}else{
    memcpy(&answer[size-n],"0",1);
    bin(n-1, answer,size);
    memcpy(&answer[size-n],"1",1);
    bin(n-1, answer,size);
}
```

}